# Problem with Ansible EC2 dynamic inventory

Tags: ansible

I am trying to use ansible dynamic inventory.

I am getting the results when I run,

```
 $ ./ec2.py --list
 ...
 ...

   "ec2": [
     "xx.xx.xx.xx"
  ]
 }
```

But when I try to run it with ansible command, it does not run successfully.

```
$ ansible -i ec2.py -e "ansible_ssh_port=3003" -m ping

Usage: ansible <host-pattern> [options]

Define and run a single task 'playbook' against a set of hosts

Options:
  -a MODULE_ARGS, --args=MODULE_ARGS
                        module arguments
  --ask-vault-pass      ask for vault password
  -B SECONDS, --background=SECONDS
                        run asynchronously, failing after X seconds
                        (default=N/A)
  -C, --check           don't make any changes; instead, try to predict some
                        of the changes that may occur
  -D, --diff            when changing (small) files and templates, show the
                        differences in those files; works great with --check
  -e EXTRA_VARS, --extra-vars=EXTRA_VARS
                        set additional variables as key=value or YAML/JSON, if
                        filename prepend with @
  -f FORKS, --forks=FORKS
                        specify number of parallel processes to use
                        (default=5)
  -h, --help            show this help message and exit
  -i INVENTORY, --inventory=INVENTORY, --inventory-file=INVENTORY
                        specify inventory host path or comma separated host
                        list. --inventory-file is deprecated
  -l SUBSET, --limit=SUBSET
                        further limit selected hosts to an additional pattern
  --list-hosts          outputs a list of matching hosts; does not execute
                        anything else
  -m MODULE_NAME, --module-name=MODULE_NAME
                        module name to execute (default=command)
  -M MODULE_PATH, --module-path=MODULE_PATH
                        prepend colon-separated path(s) to module library (def
                        ault=['/Users/luvpreetsingh/.ansible/plugins/modules',
                        '/usr/share/ansible/plugins/modules'])
  -o, --one-line        condense output
  --playbook-dir=BASEDIR
                        Since this tool does not use playbooks, use this as a
                        subsitute playbook directory.This sets the relative
                        path for many features including roles/ group_vars/
                        etc.
  -P POLL_INTERVAL, --poll=POLL_INTERVAL
                        set the poll interval if using -B (default=15)
  --syntax-check        perform a syntax check on the playbook, but do not
                        execute it
  -t TREE, --tree=TREE  log output to this directory
  --vault-id=VAULT_IDS  the vault identity to use
  --vault-password-file=VAULT_PASSWORD_FILES
                        vault password file
  -v, --verbose         verbose mode (-vvv for more, -vvvv to enable
                        connection debugging)
  --version             show program's version number and exit

  Connection Options:
    control as whom and how to connect to hosts

    -k, --ask-pass      ask for connection password
    --private-key=PRIVATE_KEY_FILE, --key-file=PRIVATE_KEY_FILE
                        use this file to authenticate the connection
    -u REMOTE_USER, --user=REMOTE_USER
                        connect as this user (default=None)
    -c CONNECTION, --connection=CONNECTION
                        connection type to use (default=smart)
    -T TIMEOUT, --timeout=TIMEOUT
                        override the connection timeout in seconds
                        (default=10)
    --ssh-common-args=SSH_COMMON_ARGS
                        specify common arguments to pass to sftp/scp/ssh (e.g.
                        ProxyCommand)
    --sftp-extra-args=SFTP_EXTRA_ARGS
                        specify extra arguments to pass to sftp only (e.g. -f,
                        -l)
    --scp-extra-args=SCP_EXTRA_ARGS
                        specify extra arguments to pass to scp only (e.g. -l)
    --ssh-extra-args=SSH_EXTRA_ARGS
                        specify extra arguments to pass to ssh only (e.g. -R)

  Privilege Escalation Options:
    control how and which user you become as on target hosts

    -s, --sudo          run operations with sudo (nopasswd) (deprecated, use
                        become)
    -U SUDO_USER, --sudo-user=SUDO_USER
                        desired sudo user (default=root) (deprecated, use
                        become)
    -S, --su            run operations with su (deprecated, use become)
    -R SU_USER, --su-user=SU_USER
                        run operations with su as this user (default=None)
                        (deprecated, use become)
    -b, --become        run operations with become (does not imply password
                        prompting)
    --become-method=BECOME_METHOD
                        privilege escalation method to use (default=sudo),
                        valid choices: [ sudo | su | pbrun | pfexec | doas |
                        dzdo | ksu | runas | pmrun | enable ]
    --become-user=BECOME_USER
                        run operations as this user (default=root)
    --ask-sudo-pass     ask for sudo password (deprecated, use become)
    --ask-su-pass       ask for su password (deprecated, use become)
    -K, --ask-become-pass
                        ask for privilege escalation password

Some modules do not make sense in Ad-Hoc (include, meta, etc)
ERROR! Missing target hosts
```

I get this long statement with the error of missing target hosts.

Then, when I run by specifying the region, it does not give any error but does not return any instances.

```
$ ansible -i ec2.py us-west-2 -e "ansible_ssh_port=3003" -m ping
 [WARNING]: Could not match supplied host pattern, ignoring: us-west-2

 [WARNING]: No hosts matched, nothing to do
```

Firstly, why is it not running? what am I doing wrong?

Secondly, why do the error changes when I specify the region? Is specifying region mandatory? shouldn't it pick the region from `ec2.ini`?

Answer (score 0):

You do not have any hosts listed.  Try adding `all` at the end of your `ansible` command:

```
ansible -i ec2.py -e "ansible_ssh_port=3003" -m ping all
```

Comment: no man, it didn't work. error - `ERROR! Extraneous options or arguments` with the same long output

Comment: Right!  The `ping` module does not take arguments.  Try this: `DEFAULT_REMOTE_PORT=3003; ansible -i ec2.py  -m ping all`

Answer (score 0):

The above command is partly right. The inventory has been specified with the -i argument but the target host group has not been specified. The command should be

```
ansible all -i ec2.py -e "ansible_ssh_port=3003" -m ping

# The command syntax could be written as below
ansible <target_host_group> -i <inventory> -e "extra_vars" -m "module_name" -a "module_arguments"
```

Please refer to the documentation on [Working with patterns](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_patterns.html#working-with-patterns) and [Ad-Hoc Commands](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/intro_adhoc.html) from the ansible documentation.